# Excel deleting my PowerQuery DataSource Permissions Credentials?

Tags: sql-server, excel, database-connection

I'm using SQLServer Database for an Excel data source and have saved the PowerQuery DataSourceSettings credentials of a Database SA login.
(Just a simple SELECT * FROM [Table] after specifying the Server and Database)

Whenever I send the file to someone else and they try to refresh the data, it prompts them for their Windows Authentication login in the attached image. It doesn't use the stored Database account I saved, and even when selecting the *'Database'* tab on the left, the credentials are blank.
[Login Dialogue Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCdZY.png)

And no, *'TrustServerCertificate=True'* is not an option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: PowerQuery authentication settings are not stored in the Excel file, but in the user profile. Also, using the `sa` credentials in applications is an awful security practice. If someone can extract/sniff your `sa` credentials then they have complete control of your SQL Server. You should instead create an application-specific account with Least Privilege security practices.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the comment! I was just being brief but yes We have a Database & Application combo specific account with Datareader and public only, thanks for your concern. 

About the first point in your reply. Does this mean every individual accessing this file would need to store the SQL account in their own data source settings?